Unable to Decode Custom IPv6 Security Header During Reassembly
I am currently working on securing IPv6 packet fragments using a custom security header that contains cryptographic information, such as a MAC and nonce. Here is the overall process I am following:
Fragmentation Process:
1. Break the Packet into Fragments:
The packet is split based on the network's MTU. Each fragment includes:
a) Standard IPv6 header
Standard Fragment Header
b) A custom Security Header containing:
- MAC: Ensures payload integrity.
- Nonce: Unique identifier for each packet.
- Security Type: Flag indicating encryption or authentication.
2. Attach the Headers and Send Fragments:
Each fragment includes the custom Security Header (serialized as JSON) and the payload.
```
Reassembly Process:
1.Fragments are received in no specific order.
2. Each fragment's custom Security Header is parsed and verified:
- MAC verification using HMAC-SHA256.
- Nonce consistency check to ensure fragments belong to the same packet.
3.Once all fragments are verified, they are buffered, sorted, and reassembled.
```
The Issue:
During reassembly, I am unable to decode the custom Security Header properly. The reassembly logic fails when parsing the header from the fragment payload.
Fragmentation logic:
from scapy.all import *
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import os


# Function to generate a MAC for fragment integrity
def generate_mac(data, key):
    """Generate HMAC-SHA256 for integrity."""
    return hmac.new(key.encode(), data, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


# Function to create a custom IPv6 Security Extension Header (serialized as JSON)
def create_security_header(nonce, mac, encryption_flag):
    """Create a custom security header and serialize it."""
    header = {
        "Next Header": 44,  # Fragment Header
        "Header Length": 4,  # Example fixed size (4 = 32 bytes)
        "Security Type": 1,  # 1 = MAC-based integrity
        "Encryption Flag": encryption_flag,
        "Nonce": nonce,
        "MAC": mac
    }
    return header  # Return the header dictionary


# Function to fragment an IPv6 packet and save the fragments to a PCAP file
def fragment_packet(packet, max_size, filename, key="secretkey"):
    """
    Fragment the packet, attach security headers, and save to PCAP.
    :param packet: The IPv6 packet to fragment.
    :param max_size: The MTU size for fragmentation.
    :param filename: The name of the .pcap file to save fragments.
    :param key: The key used for MAC generation.
    :return: List of fragments.
    """
    fragments = []
    fragment_size = max_size - 40  # IPv6 header size is 40 bytes
    payload = bytes(packet[Raw]) if Raw in packet else b""
    total_payload_len = len(payload)
    nonce = os.urandom(4).hex()  # Generate a 32-bit random nonce

    for i in range(0, total_payload_len, fragment_size):
        fragment_payload = payload[i:i + fragment_size]

        # Generate MAC for this fragment
        mac = generate_mac(fragment_payload, key)

        # Create the custom security header and serialize it to JSON
        sec_header = create_security_header(nonce, mac, encryption_flag=0)

        # Serialize the security header as JSON and ensure proper encoding
        security_header_json = json.dumps(sec_header)

        # Create the fragment header
        frag_header = IPv6(dst=packet[IPv6].dst) / \
                      IPv6ExtHdrFragment(id=12345, offset=i // 8,
                                         m=1 if i + fragment_size < total_payload_len else 0)

        # Embed the serialized JSON security header and the fragment payload together
        frag_with_sec = frag_header / Raw(load=security_header_json.encode() + fragment_payload)

        fragments.append(frag_with_sec)

    # Save all fragments to a PCAP file
    wrpcap(filename, fragments)
    print(f"Fragments saved to {filename}")

    return fragments


# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create a large IPv6 packet
    large_packet = IPv6(dst="2001:db8::1") / UDP(sport=1234, dport=80) / Raw(load="A" * 3000)

    # Fragment the packet and save to PCAP
    max_mtu = 1280  # IPv6 MTU
    fragments = fragment_packet(large_packet, max_mtu, "fragments.pcap")

    # Optionally, send the fragments
    print("Sending fragments...")
    for frag in fragments:
        frag.show()
        send(frag)

Reassembly logic:
from scapy.all import *
import hashlib
import hmac
import json


# Function to verify the MAC of a fragment
def verify_mac(fragment_payload, key, received_mac):
    """Verify the MAC of a fragment's payload."""
    calculated_mac = hmac.new(key.encode(), fragment_payload, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    return calculated_mac == received_mac


def parse_security_header(sec_header_raw):
    """Parse the security header, which is expected to be in JSON byte format"""
    if not sec_header_raw:
        print("Error: Security header is empty or malformed.")
        return None
    try:
        # Inspecting the raw security header data before parsing
        print(f"Raw security header data: {sec_header_raw[:256]}")  # Inspect the first 256 bytes
        return json.loads(sec_header_raw.decode())  # Convert the byte string back to a dictionary
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print(f"Error: Failed to decode security header. {e}")
        return None


# Function to reassemble fragments
def reassemble_fragments(fragments, key="secretkey"):
    """Reassemble fragments into the original payload."""
    fragments.sort(key=lambda frag: frag[IPv6ExtHdrFragment].offset)  # Sort by offset
    payload = b""  # Placeholder for reassembled payload
    nonce = None  # Store the nonce for consistency check

    for frag in fragments:
        # Extract the raw payload and security header (the first part of the fragment)
        raw_payload = bytes(frag[Raw])  # Extract the raw payload from the fragment

        # Extract the security header (first part of the raw payload)
        header_len = len(json.dumps({"Next Header": 44, "Header Length": 4, "Security Type": 1, "Encryption Flag": 0}).encode())
        sec_header = parse_security_header(raw_payload[:header_len])  # Adjusted to handle proper header length
        fragment_payload = raw_payload[header_len:]  # The actual fragment payload starts after the security header

        # Ensure security header is valid
        if sec_header is None:
            print(f"Invalid security header for fragment with offset {frag[IPv6ExtHdrFragment].offset}")
            return None

        # Verify MAC
        if not verify_mac(fragment_payload, key, sec_header["MAC"]):
            print(f"MAC verification failed for fragment with offset {frag[IPv6ExtHdrFragment].offset}")
            return None

        # Check nonce (ensure all fragments belong to the same packet)
        if nonce is None:
            nonce = sec_header["Nonce"]  # Set nonce from the first fragment
        elif nonce != sec_header["Nonce"]:
            print(f"Nonce mismatch for fragment with offset {frag[IPv6ExtHdrFragment].offset}")
            return None

        # Append fragment payload to the full payload
        payload += fragment_payload

    return payload


# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Simulate receiving fragments
    fragments = rdpcap("fragments.pcap")  # Read the fragments from the PCAP file

    # Reassemble fragments
    print("Reassembling fragments...")
    reassembled_payload = reassemble_fragments(fragments, key="secretkey")

    if reassembled_payload:
        print("Packet reassembled successfully:")
        print(reassembled_payload.decode())  # Decode and print the reassembled packet payload
    else:
        print("Failed to reassemble packet.")

Things I have tried:
Inspecting the Raw Security Header:
I used print(sec_header_raw[:256]) to examine the data. It seems there is extra padding or misalignment.
Header Length Calculations:
I set the expected header size explicitly to match the serialized JSON size.
JSON Decoding:
The error occurs during json.loads() when parsing the security header. It appears the raw payload contains unexpected bytes.
Questions

How can I ensure that the custom security header (JSON-encoded) is properly extracted from the fragment payload?
Could the issue be caused by improper byte alignment or padding when embedding the header and payload?

